# How to customize this wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make few changes in a wordpress page. I am able to remove few things like author name and "read more" from the page but I think I have reached my limit and can't customize more. Here is the screenshot of the page :

[image]

I want to remove the no results found and and comment below that. Tried to understand the code but unable to do it. Here is the code of the page :

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Blog Page
*/
?>
<?php 
$et_ptemplate_settings = array();
$et_ptemplate_settings = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_ptemplate_settings',true) );

$fullwidth = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] : false;

$et_ptemplate_blogstyle = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogstyle'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogstyle'] : false;

$et_ptemplate_showthumb = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showthumb'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showthumb'] : false;

$blog_cats = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogcats'] ) ? (array) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blogcats'] : array();
$et_ptemplate_blog_perpage = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blog_perpage'] ) ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_blog_perpage'] : 10;
?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
        <div class="entry<?php if($fullwidth) echo(' no_sidebar');?>">
            <div class="entry-top"></div>

            <?php get_template_part('includes/share'); ?>

            <div class="post clearfix">
                <div class="content clearfix">

                    <h1 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <?php $thumb = '';
                          $width = 184;
                          $height = 184;
                          $classtext = '';
                          $titletext = get_the_title();

                          $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'thumb');
                          $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"]; ?>

                    <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('lightbright_page_thumbnails') == 'on') { ?>                        
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>

                            <span class="overlay"></span>
                        </div> <!-- end .thumb -->
                    <?php }; ?>                 

                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.esc_html__('Pages','LightBright').':</strong> ', 'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>

                    <div id="et_pt_blog">
                        <?php $cat_query = ''; 
                        if ( !empty($blog_cats) ) $cat_query = '&cat=' . implode(",", $blog_cats);
                        else echo '<!-- blog category is not selected -->'; ?>
                        <?php 
                            $et_paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
                        ?>
                        <?php query_posts("showposts=$et_ptemplate_blog_perpage&paged=" . $et_paged . $cat_query); ?>
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                            <div class="et_pt_blogentry clearfix">
                                <h2 class="et_pt_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                                <p class="et_pt_blogmeta"><?php esc_html_e('Posted','LightBright'); ?> <?php esc_html_e('by','LightBright'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <?php esc_html_e('on','LightBright'); ?> <?php the_time(get_option('lightbright_date_format')) ?> <?php esc_html_e('in','LightBright'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link(esc_html__('0 comments','LightBright'), esc_html__('1 comment','LightBright'), '% '.esc_html__('comments','LightBright')); ?></p>

                                <?php $thumb = '';
                                $width = 184;
                                $height = 184;
                                $classtext = '';
                                $titletext = get_the_title();

                                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext);
                                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"]; ?>

                                <?php if ( $thumb <> '' && !$et_ptemplate_showthumb ) { ?>
                                    <div class="et_pt_thumb alignleft">
                                        <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
                                    </div> <!-- end .thumb -->
                                <?php }; ?>

                                <?php if (!$et_ptemplate_blogstyle) { ?>
                                    <p><?php truncate_post(550);?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore"><span><?php esc_html_e('read more','LightBright'); ?></span></a>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <?php
                                        global $more;
                                        $more = 0;
                                    ?>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_blogentry -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <div class="page-nav clearfix">
                                <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
                                else { ?>
                                     <?php get_template_part('includes/navigation'); ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .entry -->
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                    </div> <!-- end #et_pt_blog -->

                    <?php edit_post_link(esc_html__('Edit this page','LightBright')); ?>

                </div> <!-- end .content -->

                <div class="entry-bottom-top"></div>


            </div> <!-- end .post -->

            <div class="entry-bottom"></div>
        </div> <!-- end .entry -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div> <!-- end #main-area -->

    <?php if (!$fullwidth) get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can anyone please help me to make changes in this code to remove the unnecessary part of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>`

Replace this part of your page with your desire content for "No Results" or changet the `no-results template` in `include`.

Comment: Yes, It was simple. I personally removed many parts from this code apart from what you suggested. But I am not a coder, so It was difficult for me to find the function. make changes and check. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

delete this part in line 104:

```
 <?php else : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for following around line 104, and remove these lines:

```
<?php else : ?>
   <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>
```